# How to focus on a contentEditable element in Safari?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

I have a custom contentEditable element that I want to focus on, but it doesn’t work in Safari. Here is the code of the element, written using React:

```js
const card = ({ checked, onClick, text, size, inactive, color, setText, goToNext }) => {
  let editable = setText != undefined
  const inpRef = React.useRef(null)
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (text) {
      inpRef.current.textContent = text
    }
  }, [text])

  return (
    <Tappable
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`Card${size}`}
      disabled={inactive}
    >
      <div
        className={`CardContent ${checked ? 'vkuiButton--lvl-primary active' : 'vkuiButton--lvl-tertiary'}`}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: checked ? color ? color : '#4bb34b' : undefined,
          cursor: editable ? 'text' : inactive ? 'default' : 'pointer'
        }}
      >
        <div className="textwrap">
          <div
            ref={inpRef}
            contentEditable={editable}
            className='text'
            onInput={(e) => { if (editable) setText(e.target.innerText) }}
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                e.preventDefault();
                goToNext()
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Tappable>
  )
}

export default card
```

For focusing, I use `document.getElementsByClassName(‘text’)[i].focus()`, but it doesn’t work in Safari. In other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Android WebView) this works correctly.